# Nelsen's book on copulas and the Gaussian copula

Tags: copula

Has anybody any idea as to why [Nelsen's book on copulas](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387286594) is *absolutely continuous* in its silence about the Gaussian copula? It seems like an indirect statement of scorn.

Comment: It does mention the Gaussian copula: see https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/62011/919.

Comment: @whuber ...in an example about how one can obtain a non-normal joint from normal marginals! It is very telling that he says "every copula except one of the form... will suffice" (the "form" being the Gaussian copula). I have missed this, but it only re-inforces my impression that Nelsen had a beef (if you excuse my language) with the Gaussian copula. And it _still_ doesn't use its name.

Comment: He refers to them as "normal copulas" just a few years later: see http://w4.stern.nyu.edu/ioms/docs/sg/seminars/nelsen.pdf.